# IIS as Reverse Proxy - Forward Requests

Tags: iis, exchange-server, windows-server-2012-r2, url-rewrite-module

I have some issues with the reverse proxy configuration of IIS.
My goal is to catch every request to the IIS with the following
pattern:"https://myfancyserver.loc/mais/#path=/mail" and forward this to another server.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Did you tried [Microsoft Application Request Routing (AAR)](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)?

Comment: Yes, but it did not worked. I think the problem is to configure the regex pattern matching.